# Custom credential provider Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, passwords, credentials

I'm trying to create a custom credential provider for Windows 8 that will open a window that points to PWM server. I'm using a sample credential provider from Microsoft and I managed to the following: After registering the DLL, on the login screen I have an option "Sign-in Options" which enables me to click on an icon "Credencial Provider" which takes me to my PWM server. So far so good. What I would like to do is to replace the "Sing-in Options" text with "Reset Password" which on click will point to the relevant link. I can't seem to find where it might be. I'm guessing that this is not a part of Credential Provider itself but rather part of an operating system. I know it's possible because I've seen it with payed Self-service password reset solution. Just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!